# Unresponsive Ionic 1 after Cordova inAppBrowser exit under iOS 10. Works on iOS 9

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, freeze, inappbrowser

I have simplified my code to a simple app with a button that invokes inAppBrowser with the "_blank" parameter. (The same app works on iOS 9.3... not on iOS 10. It also works on Android. It works using the _system parameter on iOS 10. )

inAppBrowser runs perfectly the first time. I can enter multiple pages, type, etc. When I return to the "app" by hitting "done", the app does not respond to a touch of the button. It should be noted that the exit listener responds, but I have not found a way to revive the app (yet).

Occasionally, the app starts the browser and I exit and restart browser successfully. This happens less than 10% of the time. If it works for a while, it will typically keep working until the app is terminated. Next time it starts it pretty much is assured that it will go back to failing.

As I said, the same code works on iOS 9, Android. Using the "_system" parameter the Safari browser launches and exits and relaunches successfully and reliably. Unfortunately Apple does not like apps using Safari.

Seems like this is a common problem, but I am not finding a workaround or a solution. Anyone have a suggestion as to how to resolve?

Comment: Worthy of note. If I only display the web page and do not interact by clicking links or typing, but just return to the app, things continue to work, and I can reenter the browser repeatedly.

Comment: Also I am building on Xcode 8.3.3. Works on iOS 9 hardware and simulator. Fails on iOS 10 hardware and simulator